# How to parse an ical file and export event to a list?

Tags: python, icalendar

I have an iCal file. I would like to be able to extract all events into a list. Is there any tools or library that can do it easily? (e.g. handle the time zone info)

Python is the preferred language, but any interpretive language is OK.

Comment: Among Python libraries, vobject and icalendar look relevant, but I haven't tried either. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/vobject   http://pypi.python.org/pypi/icalendar/

Comment: I think the "vobject" libary itself (mentioned by @ThomasK) relies on this: http://labix.org/python-dateutil.  So give that a look, too.

Answer (score 2):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/ is quite a good .net library for ical. the object model is really good as well